# Integrate variable data with div tag in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have this code:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height:300px; margin: 0 auto;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

I need to replace 800px and 300px from database value;
I tried both of the below. But still i am not getting the answer.

Method 1:

```
<div id="container" style="width:'<% Response.Write(width);%>'px; height:'<% Response.Write(height);%>'px; margin: 0 auto;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Method 2:

```
<div id="container" style="width:'<%# Eval("width");%>'px; height: <%# Eval("height");%>'px; margin: 0 auto;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

The value of height and width variables are defined in page_load() function

```
int height = 300;
int width = 800;
```

This is not affecting the resulting web page. 
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: How did you declare witdh and height?

Comment: As it stands, width and height are private and inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI all,

Thanks for all the support I got answer for my own query!

This was written in designer file where i wanted the display and width and height are defined in code behind file on top of page_load() function

---

```
 <% string display= "<div id=\"container\"style=\"width:{0}px; height:{1}px; margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;\"></div";
    display= string.Format(display, width, height);   
    Response.Write(display); %>
```

---

I am not sure if it's a standard way of writing it. But it's giving me the desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using inline styles like this, you should use classes in your stylesheet and set the class attribute on the div or CssClass if it is a server control with runat="server" on it.

Have one classname in your stylesheet for each width that you want to display

```
<div id="container" class="auto <%= className %>"></div>

div.auto {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
 }


div.wide {
  width: 800px;
  height:300px; 
 }

div.narrow {
  width: 600px;
  height:300px; 
 }
```

etc...

Comment: It's unclear from the original question whether there are 2 or 3 sizes to be used, or whether he needs complete freedom to set any arbitrary size.  Pre-defined classes is cumbersome in the latter case.

Comment: Fair comment. If there are many combinations, continue with the inline approach, although I would re-consider the overall strategy if this is the case. Keeping the number of possible sizes small will make refactoring of your site a lot easier. How many times have you had to do a rebrand of a site that required new layout?

Comment: I am not sure how to use  <%= className %> and if need to pull width, height and other attributes how will it support. And does css support embeding of asp.net for this scenario. Please dont mind. I am relatively new to asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the variables *width* and *height* in your code behind page are declared with the `Protected` keyword.

```
protected int height=300;
protected int width= 800;
```

Then in your page use this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:'<%= width %>'px; height:'<%= height %>'px; 
    margin: 0 auto;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Some further advice:

- name the variable a little more specifically, live *divHeight* and  *divWeight* at least.  Something like *CentralPanelHeight* would be better.
- better is to give the dive a class attribute, get rid of your variables, and set the height and weight dynamically up top of your page, like so:

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
      div.centralPanel { 
          width: 300px;
          height: 800px; }
  </style>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
width:'<%= width %>'px;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should make your <div> a server control by adding a **runat="server"** attribute.

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

Then in a code behind you can do something like this...

```
div1.Style.Add("width", width);
div1.Style.Add("height", height);
```

The <%# Eval() %> data binding expressions will only work within the context of a databinding control.

Comment: Code behind file recognises the above codes but doesnt give the height or width which i want. I dunno why?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, inject some JQuery yumminess into your.  I know this is a different direction, but it will pretty much do what you are trying to accomplish.

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: The issue had come up by using jquery highcharts.